# How can I say "to take the derivative" (mathematics) in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, matemáticas, ciencia

In English, we generally use phrases like "take the derivative", "find the derivative", "evaluate the derivative", but we also use verbs such as "derivate", "derive", "differentiate", etc.  What are the common phrases used say it in Spanish?  Does it vary much from country to country?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Spain we use "calcular la derivada" or "obtener la derivada".

> How to take derivatives? → *¿Cómo calcular derivadas?*

An exam question may be something like:

> Find the derivative of the function f(x) = x<sup>2</sup>. → *Calcule la derivada de la función f(x) = x<sup>2</sup>.*

Comment: it's also possible to say "derivar", like: "Deriva/Derive la función f(x)=x^2"

Comment: Cierto. ese uso también es muy común. Se me ha pasado incluirlo.

Comment: No se ha oido "diferenciar"?

Comment: @Javi:  have you ever heard 'sacar la derivada'?

Comment: @Paul yes it's very common to say "sacar la derivada". You can use any verb in front of la derivada which means to get/ to calculate or something similar. Relating to "diferenciar" I have never seen using that verb in Maths. It would be for calculating "la diferencial". El diferencial y la derivada it's not the same though they are closely related: http://www.todoexpertos.com/categorias/ciencias-e-ingenieria/matematicas/respuestas/1504732/diferencias-entre-diferencial-y-derivada

Comment: Related Wikipedia articles: [Cálculo diferencial](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1lculo_diferencial) (Differential Calculus), [Diferencial de una función](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferencial_de_una_funci%C3%B3n) (Differential of a function), [Ecuación diferencial](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecuaci%C3%B3n_diferencial) (Differential equation), [Ecuación de Diferencia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaci%C3%B3n_de_recurrencia#Relaci.C3.B3n_con_la_diferencia_de_ecuaciones) (Difference equation).

Comment: @Paul Creo que es poco común usar el verbo "diferenciar" en un contexto matemático: "diferencie la función f(x)"... hasta donde yo sé, es más común usar el adjetivo "diferenciable" (la función f(x) es diferenciable) como sinónimo de "derivable"

Comment: *Derivar* means "derive" -- we would use these when talking about *deriving a formula*.  In conversation I would stick with "sacar la [primera] derivada."

Answer (score 3):

Just "derivar":

"Calcula la derivada de f(x)"
"Deriva f(x)"
"Deriva la función f con respecto a x"
...

"Derivar" has the same meaning as "Calcula la derivada" (in a mathematical context).

Comment: Also... "Sacar la derivada" (informal)